# is opencv on Anaconda the same as the opencv-python on PIP

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, opencv

I'm again trying to set up the environment for my AI Development.

`opencv-python` is the one of many package I need to install.

`conda install opencv-python` does not work as it cannot find the package.

Googled and found many suggested to use `pip` to install it.
so something like this:

`pip install opencv-python`

OR

`conda install -c conda-forge opencv`

I have this question more than a year since the last time I set up my AI environment, I think many others would have the same confusion:

**Is the `opencv-python` on PIP the same as the `opencv` on Anaconda?**

Comment: What is `same` for you. Both options will install opencv 4.4.0 and the corresponding python bindings so you can use opencv from python. But strictly speaking one is a pip package maintained by [skvark](https://pypi.org/user/skvark/) and the other one from conda-forge, i.e. a community project.So different sources but in the end, they will isntall the same thing

Comment: @FlyingTeller thanks, that's what I feel like. I installed opencv from conda and it works fine. I feel like the 2 packages are the same implementation of the OpenCV but with different people or group. So next time, if other people hit the same question, they should not worry about why opencv-python cannot be found on Conda, instead go ahead and just install `opencv` on Conda.